# How to switch between screens that are .kv files and non-.kv files in Kivy

Tags: ios, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am extremely new to kivy (and making apps in general), and I am having trouble switching between screens. I have watched several tutorials, but one of them uses a build method that returns a MDBoxLayout (CameraScreen), and the others use .kv files. I want to be able to switch between the two, or be able to reformat it so that I only use .kv files. Here is my code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.clock import Clock
import cv2
import pytesseract


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ManageDataScreen(Screen):
    pass

class CameraScreen(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.image = Image()
        self.label = MDLabel()
        layout.add_widget(self.image)
        layout.add_widget(self.label)
        self.save_img_button = MDRaisedButton(
            text="Capture",
            pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5},
            size_hint=(None, None))
        self.save_img_button.bind(on_press=self.take_picture)
        layout.add_widget(self.save_img_button)
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.load_video, 1.0/30.0)
        return layout

    def load_video(self, *args):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        #   Frame initialize
        self.image_frame = frame
        buffer = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tostring()
        texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        texture.blit_buffer(buffer, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        self.image.texture = texture

    def take_picture(self, *args):
        image_name = "img_TIMESTAMP.png"
        img = cv2.cvtColor(self.image_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3, 3), 0)
        img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
        text_data = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config="--psm 6")
        self.label.text = text_data
        cv2.imshow("cv2 final image", img)
        cv2.imwrite(image_name, self.image_frame)

GUI = Builder.load_file("kv/main.kv")
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def change_screen(self, screen_name):
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
        if screen_name == "camera_screen":
            CameraScreen().run()
        else:
            screen_manager.current = screen_name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
    MainApp().run()
```

---

and here is my main.kv file

---

```
#:include kv/home_screen.kv
#:include kv/manage_data_screen.kv

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        HomeScreen:
            name: "home_screen"
            id: home_screen
        ManageDataScreen:
            name: "manage_data_screen"
            id: manage_data_screen
```

Comment: Have you tried using ScreenManager?

Comment: Changing `Screens` is the same regardless of where the `Screen` is defined. Just set the `current` property of the `ScreenManager` to the `name` of the `Screen`.